# How to sum every value except one CPLEX

Tags: cplex

I want to sum all values except one, but I get an error message when I try to use sum(n-1 in order). Here is my code:

```
int fixed_cost = 75;
dvar int+ x[truck, order] in 0..1;
dvar float+ expected_fixed_cost[truck];

forall(h in truck) expected_fixed_cost[h] >= sum(n-1 in order) x[h,n]*fixed_cost;

minimize sum(h in truck) expected_fixed_cost[h];
```

Can someone please help me and see what I do wrong? Why does CPLEX not support the sum(n-1 in order) function?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
range truck=1..3;
range order=1..10;

int fixed_cost = 75;
dvar int+ x[truck, order] in 0..1;
dvar float+ expected_fixed_cost[truck];


minimize sum(h in truck) expected_fixed_cost[h];

subject to
{
  // sum(n in order:(n-1) in order) means
  // sum for all i in order such as n-1 belongs to order
  forall(h in truck) expected_fixed_cost[h] >= sum(n in order:(n-1) in order) x[h,n]*fixed_cost;
}
```

works fine

Comment: It works! I did not know that you needed to model it like sum(n in order:(n-1) in order) so thank you very much!!!!! Kind regards